# Change Permission to use current location in windows8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In metro style app using c# and xaml i want to use the device's location information.For that i used the following code.

```
var _geolocator = new Geolocator();
await _geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

After this a message box is showned with two options allow and block.When i chose the allow option i get the current location info.But my problem is when i choose block then i coudn't get the location after using again this code.
How can i get the location info when i opt block first and then  use this code? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is running open the charm bar (start+c), and select settings.

In the settings pane select permissions - you should see the options there to change location.